# Фреймы в opengl

Tags: графика, gui, opengl

Можно ли в `opengl` создавать фреймы? Например. для создания консоли с прокруткой.

Comment: видимо можно, раз есть такой проект: http://berkelium.org/

Comment: а в чем связь между Chromium браузером и opengl?

Comment: в том, что всё можно сделать текстурой, даже браузер chrome.

Comment: ясно спасибо за совет

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Что значит фреймы? У этого термина много разных понятий. 
Имеется ввиду отдельный буфер в который ведется отрисовка как будто это другое устройство рендеринга, и затем можно этот буфер рисовать в определенной области экрана, полностью независимо от остальных буферов? Если так то да. Называется фреймбуфер(отрисовка в текстуру).

Comment: да я это и имел в виду

Comment: было еще одно расширение, P-Buffer. В отличие от FrameBuffer(существующего в том же контексте, что и отрисовка в экран) эта штука заводит полноценный контекст OpenGL, рендерящий в текстуру и не зависящий от изменений состояний основного контекста. Оно старее FBO, но иногда полезнее.